# Apache Load Balancer on Top of Tomcat 6 - Missing Something and it's Not Working

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2, tomcat6

I'm trying to get a basic Apache 2.2 load balancer running on top of two Tomcat 6 installations.  I'm reading through all the documentation and I'm having trouble getting it working correctly.  I'm fairly certain I have the Apache configuration correct, but I think I'm missing something in my Tomcat settings that's preventing a connection.  The Tomcat Connector documentation is good for how to modify Apache, but doesn't mention what needs to change in the Tomcat settings.

Here's my basic set up.  All 3 installs are on the same machine (this is just a test setup).  So, Apache 2.2 installed in C:\apache directory.  Listens on port 80.  2 Tomcat 6 installs, one listens on port 81, one on port 82.  The Apache will simply route everything to the Tomcat servers, acting as a 100% load balancer.

Here's the errors I'm getting in my mod_jk.log file when I try to get a connection at http://localhost:80/index.jsp .  It's a 502 Bad Gateway error.

```
[Mon Nov 15 13:05:04.681 2010] [3596:1496] [error] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1245): wrong message format 0x4854 from 127.0.0.1:81
[Mon Nov 15 13:05:04.681 2010] [3596:1496] [error] ajp_get_reply::jk_ajp_common.c (2058): (tomcat1) Tomcat is down or refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet)
[Mon Nov 15 13:05:04.681 2010] [3596:1496] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2543): (tomcat1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of protocol error (attempt=1)
```

Here is the settings I have in my Apache's **httpd.conf** file...

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
<IfModule jk_module>
    JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
    JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
    JkLogLevel info
    JkMountFile conf/uriworkermap.properties
</IfModule>
```

Here is the **workers.properties** file I have...

```
#
# This file provides minimal jk configuration properties needed to
# connect to Tomcat.
#
# The workers that jk should create and work with
#
worker.list=loadbalancer,jkstatus

#
# Define the servers in our cluster
#
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
worker.tomcat1.port=81
worker.tomcat1.lbfactor=2

worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.host=localhost
worker.tomcat2.port=82
worker.tomcat2.lbfactor=1

#
# Defining a load balancer
#
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=false

#
# Define status worker
#
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

Here is the **uriworkermap.properties** I have

```
#
# This file provides sample mappings for example wlb
# worker defined in workermap.properties.minimal
# The general syntax for this file is:
# [URL]=[Worker name]

/*.*=loadbalancer
```

Finally, here's the Tomcat's Engine tag in its **server.xml** file

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat1">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />

      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" deployOnStartup="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                 directory="logs"  prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
                 pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
      </Host>

    </Engine>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the correct answer after some additional digging.  I needed to create an AJP connector in each Tomcat's server.xml file.  The Apache's mod_jk connects to this port, and then Tomcat relays that port to the HTTP Connector port.

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="81" />
```

Comment: "Tomcat relays that port to the HTTP Connector port." No it doesn't. Tomcat receives the requests directly over the AJP port. You can, and probably should, remove the HTTP connector altogether. The `redirectPort` should be set to "443".